# Jest test fails with error "DataSource is not set for this entity"

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I am building a nodejs | express API with typeorm and everything works normally when calling the routes via postman or some client. The issue appears in tests made with jest and I got the following error: **"DataSource is not set for this entity"**. Am i missing something?

- Node: 16.15.1
- "supertest": "^6.2.4",
- "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
- "typeorm": "^0.3.7",
- "typescript": "^4.7.4"
- "node-postgres": "^0.6.2",
- "form":"^7.1.0",
- "pg": "^8.7.3",
- "jest": "^28.1.3",
- "ts-jest": "^28.0.7"
- "express": "^4.18.1",

I am using a Postgres database for the tests.

jest config:

```js
module.exports = async () => {
    return {
        preset: "ts-jest",
        testEnvironment: "node",
        verbose: true,
        moduleNameMapper: {
            "@exmpl/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
          },
      };
}
```

DataSource file:

```js
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import path from "path"

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    name: "default",
    migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: false,
    entities: [path.join(__dirname, '../entities/**/*.entity.js')],
    migrations: [path.join(__dirname, '../migrations/**/*.js')],
    subscribers: [],
    cache: true
})
```

Test file:

```js
import path from "path";
import request from "supertest"
import { AppDataSource } from "../src/db/DataSource"
import { Role } from "../src/entities/User/Role.enum"
import app from "../src/App"


let connection: any;

describe('Auth', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        AppDataSource.setOptions({
            entities: [path.join(__dirname, '../dist/entities/**/*.entity.js')],
            migrations: [path.join(__dirname, '../dist/migrations/**/*.js')],
            synchronize: true,
            dropSchema: true,
        })
        connection = await AppDataSource.initialize()
        await connection.synchronize(true)
    })

    afterAll(async () => {
        await connection.destroy()
    })


    test('should signUp', async () => {
        const response = await request(app)
        .post('/auth/register')
        .send({
            firstName: "test",
            lastName: "test",
            email: "test@test.cc",
            role: Role.USER,
            status: "active",
            password: "Pa$$w0rd"
        })

        console.log(response.body)

        //Temporary pass
        expect(2+2).toBe(4)
    })
})
```

Babel config:

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
      '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
    plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators', { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { "loose": true }],
    ]
  };
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                 
    "experimentalDecorators": true,                   
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                  

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                               
    "moduleResolution": "node",                       
    "rootDirs": ["src/", "config/"],                                   
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "src/typings"],                                  

    /* JavaScript Support */

    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,                              
     "sourceMap": true,                                
     "outDir": "dist",                                   
     "removeComments": true,                           

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,           
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,           

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                     
    "noImplicitAny": true,                            
    "strictNullChecks": true,                         
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,             

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: I fixed it by reordering the imports to ensure AppDataSource was imported before my entity import.

my test file imported a seed.ts file. In the seed.ts file I imported my entity first, then my data source. Saw this error (and at other times "Entity Meta Data not found"), rearranging the order fixed it. So I wonder what the order of your imports in src/App went

Answer (score 2):

After a little research, I find out that the issue was the wrong path to the entities folder. It should not be the path to the compiled files but to the typescript source files.

I post this answer in case someone has the same issue.

I replaced this:

```js
AppDataSource.setOptions({
   entities: [path.join(__dirname, '../dist/entities/**/*.entity.js')],
   migrations: [path.join(__dirname, '../dist/migrations/**/*.js')],
   synchronize: true,
   dropSchema: true,
})
```

with this:

```js
AppDataSource.setOptions({
   entities: entities: [path.join(__dirname, '../../src/entities/**/*.entity.ts')],
   migrations: [path.join(__dirname, '../../src/migrations/**/*.ts')],
   synchronize: true,
   dropSchema: true,
})
```

I m not sure why this is like this so if someone knows to explain it would be great.